# How to get python script failure message

Tags: python, debugging, logging

This may sound a newbie question, however I'm new to python,

I'm launching python shell then typing following into it 
**from tastypie.resources import ***
The return message is

```
>>> from tastypie.resources import *
Aborted
```

The necessary modules are installed I've checked, please don't suggest running the command in separate .py file as my shell is launched with some setup by other scripts.

It there any python interpreter log (where it is located in ubuntu ?)
Is there any python configuration which debugs script execution.

P.S. python is 2.7.2+

Thanks in advance

Comment: could you post the actual output from the interpreter, with inputs and outputs. errors are normally reported.

Comment: updated the original question

Answer (score 1):

`python -vv` to trace import statements, try `python --help`.